# Automatic extension of side borders based on page content height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

I'm making a website and have "borders" around my main content. I say "borders" because its not a CSS border, but div's with a background image.

Now I have my left and right div borders (#cont-border-left/right) height set explicitly to 675px, and I have another div (#extend-l/r) just under that which I want to expand down the page when the main content goes past 675px.

I'd like to to this using only CSS if possible, but if not JavaScript/JQuery would be a great solution for me as well.

I was going to paste a bunch of the code here, but it would probably just be easier to view the source, because I think it will make more sense if you can see it all together.

Saw this on a similar question... But I'm not great with jQuery or JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
if($('#leftColumn').height() > $('#rightColumn').height())
{
$('#rightColumn').height($('#leftColumn').height());
}
else
{
$('#leftColumn').height($('#rightColumn').height());
}
});
```

And turn it into something like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
if($('#content').height() > $('#cont-border-left').height())
{
$('#extend-l').height = $('#content' - 645px)
```

^The above line needs help / correcting

```
}
else
{
$('#extend-l').height = 0
}
});
```

Any ideas on what I should try out?

### **EDIT2: Still would like to know if someone has a pure CSS solution!**

Comment: If your container width is fixed what is the use of using two seperate borders

Comment: @SVS not 100% sure what you mean by this, but the left border and right border look different, so I have them each in their own div to use the unique background image for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I was close with the edit I made.

Heres the work code should anyone need something similar in the future.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
if($('#content').height() > $('#cont-border-left').height())
    {
    $('#extend-l').height($('#content').height()-675)
    }

if($('#content').height() > $('#cont-border-right').height())
    {
    $('#extend-r').height($('#content').height()-675)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [CSS3 border-images](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images). See various:

- [css3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/): *Border-image: using images for your border*
- [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/): *Understanding border-image*
- [border-image-generator](http://border-image.com/)
- [border-image](/questions/tagged/border-image)